# Making bigger font size in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gui, font, user-interface

In QGIS my pop-up window font sizes are really small, and I don't know how to make it bigger. I have tried changing font size from `options > general > application > font`, see picture below.

Is there a way I can make the font bigger so I don't have to squint at my laptop?

[image: small font]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Restart QGIS and the changes in your font size will be visible.